# Como actualizar un choicefield en django cuando me cambie su base de datos maestra

Tags: django

Tengo dos bases de datos master-detail y cuando cambio el modelchoicefield de la primera necesito que el otro modelchoicefield de la segunda se me actualice con los datos de que forma puedo hacer esto en django, trate de adicionar un filter en el queryset pero no me funciono.

models.py

```
class areas(models.Model):
 codigo=models.CharField(max_length=1)
 descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=150)

class equipos(models.Model):
 masterArea=models.ForeignKey(areas, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=False, blank=False)
 codigo=models.CharField(max_length=15)
 descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

formularios.py

```
area=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=areas.objects.values_list('descripcion', flat=True).order_by('codigo')) # type: ignore
equipo=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=equipos.objects.values_list('descripcion', flat=True).order_by('codigo')) # type: ignore
```

todo ok en el view.py pero en el template.html al cambiar el primer ModelChoiceField áreas, no me actualiza en segundo ModelChoiceField de equipos, muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar con el tema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.